# Why can I no longer see my bridged Apple AirPort Time Capsule

Tags: time-machine, airport, time-capsule

After following [an article here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256405/is-it-possible-to-use-an-apple-time-capsule-just-as-a-network-attached-backup-dr/410571#410571?newreg=f265c4417c554864a7d97069b1b992d1), I was able to turn off the wireless features of my AirPort Time Capsule, and use the hard drive portion via my network. This worked for over a year, and recently, I can no longer see the hard drive when going to Finder in the list of folders.

Is there anyone else that has experienced this? Is there any way to retrieve this? I need the contents of my hard drive.

Comment: Did you make any changes to your Mac or network?  Did you upgrade anything?  Were updates installed?  Have you tried rebooting the TC?

Comment: Can you connect to it directly using an Ethernet cable, and then investigate it with Airport Utility? (PS. You should always have more than one copy of your files....)